# How to validate dates in Hash format in MySQL or C++

Tags: c++, mysql, hash, sha256, sha

I need to validate dates in Hash (SHA256) format in MySQL or C++.
For example: `date1 < date2` or `date1 > date2`.

I have this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT SHA1(CURDATE()) -->'2017-09-06'
```

and:

```
SELECT SHA1('2017-09-06') --> '34152f3661d73490ac89b0fe15cb3170aac06bb8'

SELECT SHA1('2017-09-07') --> '0b10f03fb245a6486d6ab5b25a2f050bf87093a5'
```

But, if I use:

```
SELECT IF (SHA1('2017-09-06') <= SHA1('2017-09-07') ,'True','False') AS Test;
```

the result is `False`, therefore, incorrect!

Comment: I'm not sure would you expect the hash functions to preserve lexical ordering

Comment: There is no such thing as 'dates in hash format'. Once hashed, these are no longer dates. Hashed data cannot reasonably be expected to have the same ordering as the original data. Your query does not return '2017-09-06'. There is nothing incorrect about the comparison result. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: And why you are securely hashing dates at all is another mystery. Dates aren't secrets, and they are shorter than the hash codes.

Comment: @GautamRai Edit rejected. It is inexcusable to remove material code from the question. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: Short answer: No, it cannot be done.  Why in the first place you are hashing a date?

Comment: @AdrianShum because I need to validate two dates (for example (current date and expiration date) applying some kind of security or difficult encoded (not Base64 encode).

Comment: Have I another options to validate two dates in a safe way using MySql or C++?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know why you'd do this, but here's a solution for you.

Here's some assumptions.

1. You were given two date hashes (two inputs)
2. You know exactly how the date hashes were created (EG: always in the format of YYYY-MM-DD)
3. You know the range of your target date (So you can reverse the hash back to the original date)

So in psudocode, you'd do something like this.

```
date getDateFromHash(string inputHash) {
  date startDate = '1911-01-01';
  date endDate = '2017-12-31';
  for(date checkDate = startDate; checkDate < endDate; checkDate + 1 day) {
    if (sha1(checkDate) = inputHash) { return checkDate }
  }
  return null;
}
date firstDate = getDateFromHash("0b10f03fb245a6486d6ab5b25a2f050bf87093a5"); // 2017-09-07
date secondDate = getDateFromHash("34152f3661d73490ac89b0fe15cb3170aac06bb8"); // 2017-09-06
if (firstDate > secondDate) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
} // compare using default date operators
```

But honestly speaking, like the comment says, there's no point of hashing date values. Hence why I'm only dropping a quich psudo code for you just to point you in the right direction, if you seriously want to tread down this path.

Comment: You can't reverse a hash.

Comment: @EJP of course you can't. However, it is possible to reverse it back if you know exactly how it was built, hence assumption 2. For example, sha1("password") will always give you 5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8, in other words, if you see that particular hash string, you can assume it's the word "password", no?

Comment: No. You can assume it's one of the very large number of strings that hash to that value,

Comment: Or, simply, "password". The chances of two identical short strings with colliding sha1 hash is basically non-existing. In the case given in the beginning, we know it's a date string, and date strings are short. Therefore, we can be safe to assume that there is no way two date will have the same SHA1 hash, and thus, it is possible to revert it by generating a list of SHA1 hashes and compare against it to find the input value.